# Write a program that compares the three numbers and prints the largest odd number

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that compares the three numbers and prints the largest odd number. Does this program below what you would write?

```
def largest_odd_number(x, y, z):
    """Write a program that compares the three numbers and prints the largest odd number"""
    odd_number_list = []
    try:
        if int(x) == x and x % 2 != 0:
            odd_number_list.append(x)
        else:
            if int(y) == y and y % 2 != 0:
                odd_number_list.append(y)
            else:
                if int(z) == z and z % 2 != 0:
                    odd_number_list.append(z)
        print(max(odd_number_list))
    except ValueError:
        print("No odd integers are found!")
```

Comment: Remove the `else`. Once the `if` is satisfied, you won't reach the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you should remove the `else` parts. Other than that, here's another way to write the same function in a simpler way and to avoid iterating over the variables 2 times:

```
def largest_odd_number(x, y, z):
    """Write a program that compares the three numbers and prints the largest odd number"""
    max_odd = -1
    for n in [x, y, z]:
        if isinstance(n, int) and (n & 1) == 1 and n > max_odd:
            max_odd = n

    if max_odd == -1:
        print("No odd integers are found!")
    else:
        print(max_odd)
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the largest odd number among 3 arguments that pass to a function would look like

```
def largest_odd_number(x, y, z):
    """Write a program that compares the three numbers and prints the largest odd number"""
    odd_number_list = []
    try:
        for i in (x, y, z):
            if int(i) % 2 != 0:
                odd_number_list.append(i)
        print(max(odd_number_list)) if odd_number_list else print("No odd integers are found!")
    except ValueError:
        print("One of the arguments can't be cast to Int")
```

This function will iterate over the 3 args and will check if each one of them is an odd number and if so it's appended to the `odd_number_list` and in the end, it will print the largest number of the `odd_number_list` variables.
In addition, this function will check if the `odd_number_list` is empty after iterating over all args and if so it will print `"No odd integers are found!"` and in the `except ValueError` part, the print will be indicate that one of the args can't be cast to int as `"One of the arguments can't be cast to Int"`.

Answer (score 0):

could you not just simplify this into a simple try/except with a list comprehension?

```
try:
    max_odd = max([num for num in [x,y,z] if int(num) % 2 != 0])
except:
    print('No odd numbers')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to allocate extra space. Since you are receiving just 3 numbers, you can proceed to the comparison without the extra list. Also, I would like to know if your numbers have at least one that is odd, and if not, what should you return?
Assuming your numbers are always positive, this code works:

```
def largest_odd_number(x, y, z):
    ans = 0
    if(x%2!=0):
        ans=x
    if(y%2!=0 and y>ans):
        ans=y
    if(z%2!=0 and z>ans):
        ans=z
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like lists and exceptions, you can use them:

```
def largest_odd_number(x, y, z):
  odd_number_list = [x for x in [ x, y, z ] if x%2 != 0 and isinstance(x, int)]
 try:
   print(max(odd_number_list))
 except ValueError:
   # if odd_number_list is empty, max() will raise ValueError
   print("No odd integers are found!")

>>> largest_odd_number(5,63.3,4)
5
>>> largest_odd_number(6,63.3,4)
No odd integers are found!
```